# How do I remove link in posts titles

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

thank you for an amazing plugin! I´m having a problem that I hope you can help me with:

I´m using List Category Posts on a private user-page with tabbed content. As I would like users to stay on their own page I was wondering if you could tell me how to remove the link from the posts title?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an expected behavior for the plugin, though I could make the link something more generic. In the meantime, you can manually change the code on your CatListDisplayer.php file, search for this:

```
    private function get_post_title($single, $tag = null, $css_class = null){
    return '<a href="' . get_permalink($single->ID).'">' . $single->post_title . '</a>';
}
```

Remove the **a** tag, and leave just this:`return $single->post_title;`

This will return just the post title, though this doesn't give you the link to the post anywhere. Is this what you need?

Comment: Hi Fernando. Yes - this is exactly what I need. Thank you so much. 

cheers

Comment: OK, glad it helped. You can mark the answer as accepted if it solved the problem. I'll look further into this on future versions of the plugin. Thanks for using it, regards!